# IBM WebSphere MQ migration to new version os

Tags: ibm-mq

We are planning to move IBM MQ v7.0.1 queue manager(s) from a Redhat v6.x Linux server on to new version of OS(linux) in our environment.
On the new server we installed IBM WebSphere MQ server version 7.0.1. 
Can you please recommended what is the best way to move the queue's to the new server and what is the necessary settings ( system queue's, etc...) that need to be set before the migration ?

Comment: You do not mention the OS and version of MQ of your current server.

Comment: hi , linux server (redhet ver 6.x)  mq server 7.0.1

Comment: I have edited the question to include the version information.  You can click edit above to correct or clarify anything further.

Comment: Please confirm if you are using a 32bit or 64bit MQ install on the old server.  The simplest way is to run `file /opt/mqm/bin/amqzxma0` and look for the string `32-bit` or `64-bit` in the output.  Please do the same for the new server.  Click edit right below your original question to add these details.

Comment: If you can provide info I requested above I can update my answer to provide some details on what is possible with that older version of MQ.

Answer (score 0):

IBM MQ version 7.0.1 has been out of support since September 30th 2015.  Version 7.1 has been out of support since April 30th 2017, and 7.5 is going out of support April 30th 2018.

If you move your mouse over the tag [[ibm-mq](/questions/tagged/ibm-mq)] and click *info* it will take you to the tag wiki for IBM MQ which lists all of the end of support dates for various versions of MQ.

If you are moving to a new server you should be going with a currently supported version of MQ.  Since 7.5 is going out of support in less than a year I would suggest you look at v8.0 or v9.0.